# How to make some cells of xlsx file as read only using openxml library

Tags: c#

I am creating xlsx file using openxml library, Every thing is working fine but now i have a requirment to make header and some sample data to be no editable, i had went through vairous link like
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KN2Q0vWMd8k
http://openxmldeveloper.org/blog/b/openxmldeveloper/archive/2011/04/15/139098.aspx

but could not find the way how to do this in my case.
Any help will be appreciated..